# Time Delay (Linux)/(Windows)

Tags: c, windows, linux

I have written a source code with a time delay.In unix I have used the

`#include <unistd.h>` header file and `usleep`  function.

What is the equivalent to this on windows?

What library and function should I use if I write the same code on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
```

and

```
::Sleep( 1000 /* milliseconds */ );
```